# Subset a vector of lists in R

Tags: r, list, dplyr, subset, tidyverse

Let's say I have a vector of lists:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tribble(
  ~x,
  c(10, 20, 64),
  c(22, 11),
  c(5, 9, 99),
  c(55, 67),
  c(76, 65)
)
```

How can I subset this vector such that, for example, I have have rows with lists having a length greater than 2? Here is my unsuccessful attempt using the tidyverse:

```
filter(d, length(x) > 2)
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  x        
  <list>   
1 <dbl [3]>
2 <dbl [2]>
3 <dbl [3]>
4 <dbl [2]>
5 <dbl [2]>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be `lengths` as the 'x' is a `list`

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
     filter(lengths(x) > 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `subset()` + `lengths()`

```
subset(d,lengths(x)>2)
```